# Conditional Expectation of random walk square $E^{F_n}X_{n+1}^2$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, martingales, random-walk

$X_n$ is simple random walk

It seems like $E^{F_n}[X_{n+1}^2]=X_n^2+1$

And $E^{F_n}[X_{n+1}^4]=X_n^4+6X_n^2+1$

I think the first expression is due to $X_n^2$ being positve

But how does it reach the second conclusion?

Comment: write $X_{n+1} = X_{n} + \xi_{n+1}$ where $\xi_{n+1}$ is independent to $\mathcal{F}_n$

Comment: @BGM Also $E[X_n\zeta_{n+1}]=0$ due to the independence of $X_n$ and $\zeta_{n+1}?$

Comment: Yes correct - $E[X_n\xi_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_n}] = X_nE[\xi_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_n}] = X_n \times 0 = 0$